How to improve the response time of FastAPI endpoint, which accepts DXF files and returns the PDF made using the Matplotlib backend,
i am using matplotlib backend (ezdxf drawing addons) to convert dxf to pdf using the matplotlib.qsave method. It converts perfectly. But it takes 15 seconds for this conversion. Is there any way alternative to get conversion faster?
i used matplotlib.qsave method. i want the response time to be faster

Try the PyMuPdfBackend it's faster than the MatplotlibBackend.

This is taking still longer time. get_pdf_bytes() function is not getting completed even after 5 minutes.

any other solutions please...
